# If value found in multidimensional array, then make a change

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array stored in `$t_comments`:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 889
            [1] => First comment
            [2] => 8128912812
            [3] => approved
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 201
            [1] => This is the second comment
            [2] => 333333
            [3] => approved
        )

    // There is more...
)
```

I loop through the array like this:

```
foreach($t_comments as $t_comment) {
    $id = $t_comment[0]; // id
    $comment = $t_comment[1]; // comment
    $timestamp = $t_comment[2]; // timestamp
    $status = $t_comment[3]; // status
}
```

My question: How do I loop through the array searching in `$id` for a value like `201`, and if it matches, then change `$status` within that array to `deleted`?

For example:

```
foreach($t_comments as $t_comment) {
    $id = $t_comment[0]; // id
    $comment = $t_comment[1]; // comment
    $timestamp = $t_comment[2]; // timestamp
    $status = $t_comment[3]; // status

    if ($id == '201') {
       // change $status value of this specific array to 'delete'
       // WITHOUT changing the order of the arrays!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing loop is nearly there. To be able to modify a value inside a `foreach` loop and have that actually reflected in the original array, you need to use a reference `&`. This is among the first examples [in the `foreach` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

No changes made will have any effect on the order of the original outer array or the modified sub-array. [Demonstration...](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Kp4qZX)

Just overwrite  `$t_comment[3]` inside the loop with your new value:

```
// You must use a reference &t_comment to modify this
foreach($t_comments as &$t_comment) {
    $id = $t_comment[0]; // id
    $comment = $t_comment[1]; // comment
    $timestamp = $t_comment[2]; // timestamp
    $status = $t_comment[3]; // status

    if ($id == '201') {
        // Set a new value for the [3] key
        // Don't modify the variable $status unless it was also
        // declared as a reference. Better to just modify the array
        // element in place.
        $t_comment[3] = 'deleted';
    }
}
```

Without using a reference, you can also modify it by array key if you use the `$key => $value` form of `foreach`:

```
// Use the $key => $value form
foreach($t_comments as $key => $t_comment) {
    $id = $t_comment[0]; // id

    if ($id == '201') {
        // Set a new value for the [3] key
        // Referencing the *original array variable* by key
        // rather than the iterator $t_comment
        $t_comments[$key][3] = 'deleted';
    }
}
```

Comment: "Without using a referenceyou can also modify it by array key if you use the $key => $value.."  you sure?